# Autograd.grad() with create_graph=True for Sparse Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, sparse-matrix, autograd

I’m trying to use torch.autograd.grad with create_graph=True to calculate the gradient with respect to one parameter (Let’s say **A**) then calculate the gradient of the previous gradient with respect to other parameters (Let’s say **B**).

The thing is, **A** is dense and **B** is sparse. The following is an example.

```
x = torch.sparse_coo_tensor([[0], [1]], [1.], (2,2), requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([[1., -1.], [1., 1.]], requires_grad=True)
n = torch.norm(torch.sparse.mm(x, y))
g = torch.autograd.grad(n, y, create_graph=True)
```

Then I get an error: " The backward pass for this operation requires the ‘self’ tensor to be strided, but a sparse tensor was given instead. Please either use a strided tensor or set requires_grad=False for ‘self’ "

I understand that torch.sparse.mm will produce SparseAddmmBackward grad_fn so it’s different from normal cases. But I can’t figure out a solution based on this fact.

I wonder if there is any way to solve this problem (To calculate the gradient of g with respect to x in the above code). Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try just using n.backward() instead.

```
>>> import torch
>>> x = torch.sparse_coo_tensor([[0], [1]], [1.], (2,2), requires_grad=True)
>>> y = torch.tensor([[1., -1.], [1., 1.]], requires_grad=True)
>>> n = torch.norm(torch.sparse.mm(x, y))
>>> n.backward()
>>> #g = torch.autograd.grad(n, y, create_graph=True)
>>> print(x.grad)
tensor(indices=tensor([[0],
                       [1]]),
       values=tensor([1.4142]),
       size=(2, 2), nnz=1, layout=torch.sparse_coo)
>>> print(y.grad)
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.7071, 0.7071]])
```

Populates the gradients as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I'm trying to find the gradient of a function of g, wrt. x. For example the gradient of `torch.norm(g)` wrt. the sparse tensor x.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what is happening here? You are backpropagating from n, so it's derivate w.r.t. x is going to be stored in x.grad.

Comment: I want to calculate `torch.norm(g)` 's gradient, which is equivalent to `torch.norm(y.grad)` 's gradient.

Answer (score 0):

I find [this function](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_sparse#sparse-dense-matrix-multiplication) can solve my problem.

```
x = torch.sparse_coo_tensor([[0], [1]], [1.], (2,2), requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([[1., -1.], [1., 1.]], requires_grad=True)
x1 = x.coalesce()
n = torch.norm(torch_sparse.spmm(x1.indices(), x1.values(),
 x1.size()[0], x1.size()[1], y))
g = torch.norm(torch.autograd.grad(n, y, create_graph=True)[0])
g.backward()
```